# My loop keeps on multiplying by the number of values

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, range

Say I have these students with their corresponding grades and weights:

```
grades = {'terri': [55,90,10], 'kerry': [88,66,77], 'sherry': [70, 90,10], 'jerry': [90, 60, 90], 'hari': [0, 100, 97]}

weights = [20,40,40]
```

I then want to create a function that finds the weighted average

```
def final_grade(gr,wghts):
    """
    input: A dict (with students as keys & a list of length n) and a set of weights for each assignment (length n)
    output: list of pairs (stu_nam/grade)
    """
    its=range(len(wghts))
    weigh_grad={}
    for stu in gr:
        for grads in gr[stu]:
            for i in its:
                if stu not in weigh_grad:
                    weigh_grad[stu]=(gr[stu][i]*wghts[i])/100
                else:
                    weigh_grad[stu]+=(gr[stu][i]*wghts[i])/100
    return weigh_grad

final_grade(grades,weights)
```

My output is:

```
>>> {'terri': 153.0,'kerry': 224.40000000000003,'sherry': 162.0,'jerry': 234.0,'hari': 236.39999999999998}
```

Use the example of Terri. Their weighted average is actually 51. It has trebled. The same occured to Kerry and so on. All of my outputs are treble what I expected.

Comment: you need to divide the final value `weigh_grad` bythe lenght of the array otherwise you are not computing an average

Comment: @JohnnyMopp While I though that at first too, that's not the issue. The issue is the extra for loop that isn't used, but runs the inner loop code three times.

Answer (score 1):

Every key in a dictionary is unique. You are iterating over each key too many times and writing over the value stored at that key.

Code:

```
grades = {'terri': [55,90,10], 'kerry': [88,66,77], 'sherry': [70, 90,10], 'jerry': [90, 60, 90], 'hari': [0, 100, 97]}

weights = [20,40,40]

def final_grade(gr,wghts):
    """
    input: A dict (with students as keys & a list of length n) and a set of weights for each assignment (length n)
    output: list of pairs (stu_nam/grade)
    """
    weigh_grad={}

    for stu, grads in gr.items():
        weigh_grad[stu] = 0.0
        for idx, g in enumerate(grads):
            weigh_grad[stu] += g * wghts[idx] / 100
            
    return weigh_grad
```

Output:

```
{'terri': 51.0, 'kerry': 74.8, 'sherry': 54.0, 'jerry': 78.0, 'hari': 78.8}
```

Comment: instead of hardcoding `wghts[idx] / 100`, you could write `wghts[idx] / sum(wghts)`

Comment: I prefer to keep the code as close to the original as possible, so it makes more sense to the person asking the question, and is easier for them to convert from incorrect code -> correct code.

Comment: I think beginners most of the time copy paste code from the answers, plus if you have the opportunity to enhance the code a little, why not do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and `sum`.

```
def final_grade(gr,wghts):
    for k,v in gr.items():
        gr[k] = sum((a*b)/100 for a,b in zip(wghts, v))
    return gr
```

Output:

```
>>> grades = {'terri': [55,90,10], 'kerry': [88,66,77], 'sherry': [70, 90,10], 'jerry': [90, 60, 90], 'hari': [0, 100, 97]}
>>> weights = [20,40,40]
>>> final_grade(grades,weights)
{'terri': 51.0, 'kerry': 74.8, 'sherry': 54.0, 'jerry': 78.0, 'hari': 78.8}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```py
for grads in gr[stu]
```

Use this instead, your code is running three more times because of the extra for loop:

```py
def final_grade(gr,wghts):
    """
    input: A dict (with students as keys & a list of length n) and a set of weights for each assignment (length n)
    output: list of pairs (stu_nam/grade)
    """
    its=range(len(wghts))
    weigh_grad={}
    for stu in gr:
        s = 0
        for i in its:
            s+=(gr[stu][i]*wghts[i])/100
        weigh_grad[stu]=s
    return weigh_grad
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

```py
def final_grade(grades_per_student, wghts):
    """
    input: A dict (with students as keys & a list of length n) and a set of weights for each assignment (length n)
    output: list of pairs (stu_nam/grade)
    """
    total_weight = sum(wghts)
    weighted_averages = {}

    for student, student_grades in grades_per_student.items():

        weighted_averages[student] = 0

        for index, grade in enumerate(student_grades):
            weighted_averages[student] += grade * wghts[index] / total_weight

    return weighted_averages
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grades = {'terri': [55,90,10], 'kerry': [88,66,77], 'sherry': [70, 90,10], 'jerry': [90, 60, 90], 'hari': [0, 100, 97]}

weights = [20,40,40]

di = {}

for e in grades:
    
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        if e not in di:
            di[e] = grades[e][i] * weights[i]/100
        else:
            di[e] += grades[e][i] * weights[i]/100

print(di)
```

Out:

```
{'terri': 51.0, 'kerry': 74.8, 'sherry': 54.0, 'jerry': 78.0, 'hari': 78.8}
```